# Maven dependency conflict: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/NotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hbase, velocity

I added to my application's pom the org.apache.hbase:HBase-client:1.2.5 dependency and my application stopped working. It seems like a dependency conflict, but I can't figure it out, what is the exact problem.

I get the following exception:

```
<Jun 4, 2019 6:48:32,171 AM CDT> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <Jun 04, 2019 6:48:32 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
SEVERE: An exception has been thrown from an exception mapper class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/NotFoundException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler.toResponse(GenericExceptionHandler.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler.toResponse(GenericExceptionHandler.java:43)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.mapException(ServerRuntime.java:601)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:476)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3702)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)>

<Jun 4, 2019 6:48:32,172 AM CDT> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <Jun 04, 2019 6:48:32 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
SEVERE: An exception was not mapped due to exception mapper failure. The HTTP 500 response will be returned.
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3702)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)>
<Jun 4, 2019 6:48:32,734 AM CDT> <Error> <org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder> <BEA-000000> <An exception has been thrown from an exception mapper class org.apache.hadoop.yar
n.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/NotFoundException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler.toResponse(GenericExceptionHandler.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler.toResponse(GenericExceptionHandler.java:43)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.mapException(ServerRuntime.java:601)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:476)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have tried to use other versions of the hbase-client but without any success.

Dependencies in my pom.xml:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please check the dependency hierarchy; seems there is a version mismatch for jersey.

Comment: I checked it, but I don't see any jersey dependency. I'm not using jersey at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be that you use too old version of java for that jars requirement ? 
because i see  you use really old version of spring ...
and also there are 2 different versions of velocity related things, this might be also causing some mismatches .

Comment: Velocity versions are old, but correct. 1.7 for the engine and 2.0 for the tools.

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be due to the version mismatch of Jersey.

HBase uses a particular Jersey version.
Your application or any other dependency might use another Jersey version.
When Jersey jars are loaded, some dependent classes would be missing depending on the version that is loaded.

So look into the packages that use Jersey and change it into common version. This is also one of the reasons for `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception.